# SD Flash Card Read-Only Issue

Tags: usb-flash-drive, formatting, sd-card, read-only

recently during re-partitioning my hard disk, I mistook SD flash drive as some sort of "extra" "wasted" space and deleted it.
ever since my computer(s) stopped recognizing it.

I happen to have access to Linux system, Windows OS; and MacOS systems; Linux (Ubuntu) and Windows 10; can recognize it can see what's inside it; but cannot make any chances.

like, creating a folder, or storing another file it.

on Mac, weird and interestingly, it seems like I can write as well (since this is work computer, didn't want to copy anything from Mac ...), but I was able to create two folders, even renamed one of the folders after created it.

can anyone explain to me how can I make it recognizable in my other OSs as well?

about Mac, I vaguely remember it uses a different Technoloy for its storage, I can kind of feel since the technology kin to SF flash drive tech behind it, that could be why they can communicate with each other. (The reason I mention this is to say, it seems like Flash Driver should be still "alive", it's not dead like [this article](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-how-to-fix-read-only-usb-drive/) said (to be fair and respectfully, this article taught me something I didn't know before today)

Thank you everyone in advance! I hope there is a way to get this SD card back to normal.

Comment: Additionally, before it worked on Mac, I thought it was the 3rd scenario from the article I mentioned in the post. Me being able to create folders changed my mind about that conclusion. If it's still valid, why MacOS is so special enough to made it work.

Comment: Double check the new folders you wrote & renamed. Are they still there if you unmount then re-mount the drive?

Comment: Hi @Tetsujin, thank you for your response!! it's still there, in neither OS (Linux nor Windows 10) I can do anything)

Comment: Check what format it is. Disk Utility - Press Cmd/2 so you can see the devices as well as the volumes. Click the device, check the Partition Map: format, then the volume & check the Type: If it's APFS or HFS, only the Mac will be able to read/write properly. if you need it to be read/written cross-platform, you will need to reformat it as ExFAT.